# What word describes the unique possibilities when disambiguating a word?

Tags: single-word-requests

The [disambiguation page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_(disambiguation)) for the word `turtle` on wikipedia displays a list of possibilities to choose from.

Many of these possibilities are just the same word "turtle" but with different meanings.

Is there a noun for these possible choices, for instance if this was a list of `disambiguations` then each entry might be a `disambiguate` (used as a noun and pronounced /ˌdisamˈbiɡyəˌwat/ and not as a verb pronounced /ˌdisamˈbiɡyəˌwāt/, not a word but hopefully helps clarify what I am trying to find)?

Said another way, the precise term for an unambiguous pairing of a word and one of its possible meanings together.

I thought `term` might be close to what I was looking for the answer to [What is the difference between a term and a word?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/146450/what-is-the-difference-between-a-term-and-a-word/146455) seemed to indicate that `term` wouldn't be the right word.

Comment: As you are asking for a technical term about language (and one that applies to any language, not just English), I suggest you ask here https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Different **uses** of the word?

Comment: What does "_ust the same word "turtle" but with different meanings_ mean? They all say _turtle_? Or they're different words for turtles? Or they're different meanings for the word _turtle_? Giving some examples is generally better than trying to describe something technical you don't know the terms for.

Comment: As others, and indeed yourself, say, the disambiguation page disambiguates between different *meanings* of a word, or between different *uses* of the same meaning, or between both. In any case, the target pages are called the target pages, at least they were when I was still participating.

Comment: Generically, they’re *options* for the search word.